# Cordova EmailComposer Plugin - callback function is not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

### Short description:

I develop an Android app using Phonegap 3.5.0 (JavaScript, CSS3 and HTML5) on Windows. The main function of the application is to fill a form and send it by e-mail using smartphone's Gmail client. In detail, a user clicks the Send button in app's main view after the form is filled and he will be prompted to choose e-mail client options. He will pick Gmail and send the pre-composed e-mail.

### What do I need:

I need to know when the email view has been dismissed to navigate the app to another view that will show that e-mail has been successfully sent (if it was). From now I will call it success page.

### What do I have:

I use the Cordova EmailComposer Plugin and its callback option. It is described on the official GitHub page:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

> The open method supports additional callback to get informed when the
>   view has been dismissed.

```
window.plugin.email.open(properties, function () {
    console.log('email view dismissed');
}, this);
```

In my app I have this piece of code that triggers the e-mail view.

```
        window.plugin.email.open({
            to: to,
            subject: subject,
            body: body
        }, function(){
            $.mobile.changePage($("#emailSent"), "fade", true, true); //callback function to navigate to the "success" page after the e-mail view has been dismissed.    
        }, this);
```

### **The problem:**

The app returns to the same page from where the user pressed the Send button  after an e-mail has been sent. There is no redirection to the "success" page.

Main question:
What am I implementing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For the callback, take a look at this example: http://plugins.telerik.com/plugin/emailcomposer

Maybe your plugin version is not the latest because the callback has been recently (re)added.

Comment: Removed and added the plugin once again, callback does not work. I had, and still have Version 0.8.1 because Version 0.8.2 is not yet released according to the official link and your link. Anyway thanks for the suggestion.